# Error al subir archivos en un dropzone (sólo cuando se publica en el servidor la app web)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dropzone

Buenas tardes, tengo una aplicación web en asp.net, en ésta aplicación web, tengo un dropzone, donde cargo archivos arrastrándolos, todo funciona perfecto cuando hago pruebas, los archivos se insertan perfectamente en la bd, pero cuando publico la aplicación, ya no funciona la carga de archivos, aquí dejo el código, espero me puedan ayudar

Ésto es la parte de C#

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            // context.Response.Write("Hello World");
            XmlSerializer xml_serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cLogin));
            StringReader string_reader = new StringReader(CookieUtils.LeeValorCookie(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nombreCookie"]));
            cLogin myLogin = (cLogin)xml_serializer.Deserialize(string_reader);

            string str_image = "";
            String folder = context.Request.Params["folder"].ToString();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(folder))
            {
                String[] valores = folder.Split('_');

                string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/");
                string[] files;
                int numFiles;
                files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
                numFiles = files.Length;
                numFiles = numFiles + 1;

                foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
                    string fileName = file.FileName;
                    String tmpFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                    String tmpExtension = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                    Decimal noVersion = ArchivoVersion(tmpFileName);
                    String tmpVersion = String.Format("_v{0:00}_", noVersion);
                    fileName = tmpFileName + tmpVersion + String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", System.DateTime.Now) + tmpExtension;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                    {
                        //fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                        //str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
                        string pathToSave = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/") + fileName.Trim();  // str_image;
                        file.SaveAs(pathToSave);

                        Archivos archi = new Archivos();
                        int order = archi.GetOrden(Convert.ToInt32(valores[1]));

                        // Save to database
                        Byte[] contenido = new Byte[] { };
                        con.Open();
                        contenido = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToSave);
                        String sQuery = "INSERT INTO ValueCategoriaArchivo (Nombre, IdCategoriaPadre, Borrado, EsArchivo, Archivo, FechaRegistro, Orden, IdUsuarioCreador, empresa, llave, Version, FechaVersion, llaveRazon, llaveEmp, llaveCreador) VALUES " +
                                        "(@Nombre, @IdCategoriaPadre, 0, 0, @Archivo, GetDate(), @Orden, @IdUsuarioCreador, @empresa, newId(), @Version, GetDate(), @llaveRazon, @llaveEmp, @llaveCreador)";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, con);

                        cmd.CommandText = sQuery;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = fileName.Trim();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("IdCategoriaPadre", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = valores[1];
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Archivo", SqlDbType.VarBinary)).Value = contenido;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Orden", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = order;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("IdUsuarioCreador", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = myLogin.UsrId;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("empresa", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = myLogin.EmpId;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Version", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = noVersion;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("llaveRazon", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = myLogin.llaveRazon;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("llaveEmp", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = myLogin.llaveEmpresa;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("llaveCreador", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = myLogin.llaveEmpleado;
                        int filas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        //String ejecuta = bdBase.bdExecute(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conDatabase"].ConnectionString, cmd);
                        // Delete file
                        try
                        {
                            File.Delete(context.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/" + fileName.Trim()));
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { }
                    }
                }
            }
            context.Response.Write(str_image);
        }
```

y Aquí la parte de JS dónde cargo los archivos

```
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            $('#my-dropzone').dropzone({
            url: getBaseUrl() + 'FileUpld.ashx',
            maxFiles: 10,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            init: function () {
            this.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append('folder', $('#valorFolder').val());
            });
            },
            accept: function (file, done) {
            var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
            var ext = re.exec(file.name)[1];
            ext = ext.toUpperCase();
            if (ext == "JPG" || ext == "PDF") {
            done();
            }
            else {
            done("Sólo seleccione imagenes JPG, y archivos PDF.");
            swal("Aviso", "Sólo se pueden subir imágenes JPG y documentos PDF", "warning");
            }
            },
            success: function (file, response) {
            var fName = response;
            swal("Éxito", "El archivo se subió correctamente", "success");                                                      
            file.previewElement.classList.add('dz-success');
            RefrescaArchivos();
            },
            removedfile: function (file, serverFileName) {
            var file_name = file.name;
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: getBaseUrl() + 'FileDlt.ashx?filename=' + file_name,
                    success: function (response) {
                    var _ref;
                    return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
                    }
                  });
                },
                    error: function (file, response) {                                                          file.previewElement.classList.add('dz-error');
                    swal("Error", response.d, "error");
                                                    }
                                                });
```

Se queda así el dropzone y no sube la imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que es lo que no funciona exactamente?

Comment: @gbianchi, La subida a la bd es lo que falla, no se suben los archivos, se quedan así cómo en la imagen, en rojo, y cuando lo hago en modo Debug, lo hace perfecto, todos los archivos que subo al dropzone, se insertan en la bd

Comment: y no tira ningun error? o algo?

Comment: No, es lo raro, que no suelta ningún error, quise mostrar el error en un alert, pero no arroja nada :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer había un problema la crear el directorio `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath"~/MediaUploader/"`

que era donde se guardaba temporalmente el "archivo", así que tuve que implementar un método para no tener que guardar el "archivo" en el directorio y me lo guardara en memoria

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

y así quedo finalmente

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            XmlSerializer xml_serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cLogin));
            StringReader string_reader = new StringReader(CookieUtils.LeeValorCookie(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nombreCookie"]));
            cLogin myLogin = (cLogin)xml_serializer.Deserialize(string_reader);
                string str_image = "";
                String folder = context.Request.Params["folder"].ToString();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(folder))
                {
                    String[] valores = folder.Split('_');
                    string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/");
                    string[] files;
                    int numFiles;
                    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
                    numFiles = files.Length;
                    numFiles = numFiles + 1;

                    foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
                        string fileName = file.FileName;
                        String tmpFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                        String tmpExtension = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                        Decimal noVersion = ArchivoVersion(tmpFileName);
                        String tmpVersion = String.Format("_v{0:00}_", noVersion);
                        fileName = tmpFileName + tmpVersion + String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", System.DateTime.Now) + tmpExtension;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                        {
                            Archivos archi = new Archivos();
                            int order = archi.GetOrden(Convert.ToInt32(valores[1]));
                            Byte[] contenido = new Byte[] { };
                            contenido = ReadFully(file.InputStream);
                            String sQuery = "INSERT INTO ValueCategoriaArchivo (Nombre, IdCategoriaPadre, Borrado, EsArchivo, Archivo, FechaRegistro, Orden, IdUsuarioCreador, empresa, llave, Version, FechaVersion, llaveRazon, llaveEmp, llaveCreador) VALUES " +
                                            "(@Nombre, @IdCategoriaPadre, 0, 0, @Archivo, GetDate(), @Orden, @IdUsuarioCreador, @empresa, newId(), @Version, GetDate(), @llaveRazon, @llaveEmp, @llaveCreador)";
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                            cmd.CommandText = sQuery;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = fileName.Trim();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("IdCategoriaPadre", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = valores[1];
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Archivo", SqlDbType.VarBinary)).Value = contenido;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Orden", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = order;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("IdUsuarioCreador", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = myLogin.UsrId;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("empresa", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = myLogin.EmpId;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Version", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = noVersion;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("llaveRazon", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = myLogin.llaveRazon;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("llaveEmp", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = myLogin.llaveEmpresa;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("llaveCreador", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = myLogin.llaveEmpleado;
                            String ejecuta = bdBase.bdExecute(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conDatabase"].ConnectionString, cmd);

                            SendGrid2.EnviarMensajeError("Ejecuto", ejecuta);
                        }
                    }
                }
                context.Response.Write(str_image);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var ahora = DateTime.Now;
                SendGrid2.EnviarMensajeError("Error en fileupid", "", ex);              
            }
        }
```